# Play Framework Production on Windows

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

The [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production) states that there is no production support for the Play Framework on Windows.

> Note play is not supporting windows in production mode, therefore stage and start won’t work under windows

I was wondering why this is the case.

Also, is this due to limitations that will be overcome, or is Windows not a first-class target platform?

Comment: Maybe answers to that issue can help you: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/920-play-start-crashes-on-windows-play-run-works, I work on unixes, so can't verify that

Answer (score 2):

We have had success with using the [Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) to run Play applications on Windows in production.

We use `dist` to package the application for distribution, then install as a Windows service using the Commons Daemon.

Answer (score 1):

The `stage` feature uses `chmod`, see [this line of code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/17e66abdbe9abdd8d5c98a3f62ef1149f36c642e/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala#l200). As for the `dist` and `start` feature I am not quite sure. As @biesior pointed out, [this ticket](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/920-play-start-crashes-on-windows-play-run-works) might provide a workaround.